# Using Docker to pull an AWS ECS image that is named in mixed case

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Docker seems to want everything in its world in lowercase. AWS doesn't. My company has an image on ECS that is named in mixed case. It's whole name reads as:

> BlastComputeEnvironment-G2nuvesECl8RckPI_Batch_bfa38d06-e569-33b8-8691-ff38312a553a

[This document](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-locally-pull-docker-image-from-aws-ecr-ebebbb4c100) would suggest that using the docker commandline command is a good way to pull images from ECS. But it's complaining at me:

> invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

What to do?

Comment: Change it to be lower case?

Comment: The error message is complaining about the repository name. You have posted an image name in your question. What is the repository name?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an odd difference between the AWS console versus the AWS command line interface. If I make the inquiry by console, I get mixed case. If I make the inquiry by CLI, I get what I need:

```
% aws ecr describe-repositories
```

gets me information such as:

```
`repositoryUri": "<account number>".dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsbatch/awsbatch_run_blast"`
```

and this works, **when followed by an appropriate tag**.  The console is useful for seeing what tags exist.